# Cleanly removing hashes from an array of hashes based on nested values

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap, unique

I've run into a bit of an interesting situation. I want to remove values from an array of hashes if a specific value in that array is a duplicate. Here's an example of the structure I'm working with:

```
[
  {
    "PCDBPart": {
      "Category": {
        "ID": 22,
        "Name": "Wiper and Washer"
      }
    },
    "Position": {
      "Name": "Right",
      "PCDBPositionID": 12,
      "PositionID": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "PCDBPart": {
      "Category": {
        "ID": 22,
        "Name": "Wiper and Washer"
      }
    },
    "Position": {
      "Name": "Right",
      "PCDBPositionID": 12,
      "PositionID": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "PCDBPart": {
      "Category": {
        "ID": 24,
        "Name": "Wiper and Washer"
      }
    },
    "Position": {
      "Name": "Right",
      "PCDBPositionID": 2,
      "PositionID": 4
    }
  }
]
```

The issue I have is that the values in `Position` are duplicated often, making the array large. I want to return the array with hashes unique by the `PositionID` they contain.

I tried using `my_array.uniq { |h| h.dig(:Position, :PositionID)}`, but that just seems to return one value:

```
[
  {
    "PCDBPart": {
      "Category": {
        "ID": 22,
        "Name": "Wiper and Washer"
      }
    },
    "Position": {
      "Name": "Right",
      "PCDBPositionID": 12,
      "PositionID": 10
    }
  },
]
```

Here's the desired output:

```
[
  {
    "PCDBPart": {
      "Category": {
        "ID": 22,
        "Name": "Wiper and Washer"
      }
    },
    "Position": {
      "Name": "Right",
      "PCDBPositionID": 12,
      "PositionID": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "PCDBPart": {
      "Category": {
        "ID": 24,
        "Name": "Wiper and Washer"
      }
    },
    "Position": {
      "Name": "Right",
      "PCDBPositionID": 2,
      "PositionID": 4
    }
  }
]
```

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: I don't understand. There are only two keys `:PCDBPositionID` and they have different values (`12` and `2`), so there are no duplicates. When you give an example you should always show the desired return value. Your title correctly refers an array of hashes, but you got that backward in the text. This is a pure-Ruby question so I suggest you remove the Rails tag, so that any readers who filter on "ruby" but filter out "rails" will see your question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right. Edited the question so input/output is more specific.

Comment: If `arr` is your array you could simply write `a = arr.uniq`. Then `a.size #=> 2; a[0] == arr[0] #=> true; a[1] == arr[2] #=> true`, but that's only because, in your example, the first to hashes in `arr` (`arr[0]` and `arr[1]`) are equal. If `arr[0][:Position][:PCDBPositionID]` equals `arr[1][:Position][:PCDBPositionID]` when `arr[0]` does not equal `arr[1]` we need to know which hash to keep, `arr[0]` or `arr[1]`.